# python tkinter) how do I command the button to callback class?

Tags: python, class, button, callback, tkinter

I want my santa button to callback my d_day class when its clicked but I'm not sure how to do it. 
Below is the source code I've got so far! I've run it but nothing happens.. nothing running, no errors whatsoever. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?
Thanks a lot!

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import datetime

root = Tk()

class D_day:
    def __init__(self, root, time):   
        self.root = root
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.dDay = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%m/%d/%y")
        self.calDays = Label(self.frame)
        self.count = Button(self.frame, text="Countdown", background='green', command=lambda:self.root.after(1000, self.update))
        self.daysLabel = Label(self.frame, text="Days left until (mm/dd/yy):")
        self.dDayE = Entry(self.frame)
        self.dDayE.insert(0, time)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.calDays.grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan=3)
        self.count.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=2)
        self.daysLabel.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.dDayE.grid(row=3, column=2)

    def update(self):
        remaining = self.dDay-datetime.datetime.now()
        daysRemaining = remaining.days
        self.calDays.config(text="HoHoHo {days} days until Christmas!".format(days=daysRemaining))
        self.root.after(1000, self.update)

d = D_day(root, "12/25/13")


c = Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, background='black')
c.create_text(250, 90, text="Merry Christmas", font='Times 28 bold italic', fill='red')
c.create_text(250, 130, text="and", font='Times 15 bold italic', fill='white')
c.create_text(250, 170, text="Happy New Year", font='Times 28 bold italic', fill='green')
c.pack()

flake = []
for i in range(80):
    flake.append(c.create_text(random.randrange(500), random.randrange(400), text="*", fill='white', font='Times 27'))

santa = Button(root, text = "Click me!", foreground = 'red', compound = TOP, command=d)
photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/python/santa.gif")
santa.config(image = photo, width = 90, height = 140)
santa_window = c.create_window(250, 350, anchor = S, window=santa)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try to build your code step-by-step. So first, make sure you can draw the main canvas, then add widgets, then add buttons and other events. Coding in an iterative manner will help you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following template to suit your needs:

```
class D_day:
    def __init__(self, root):   
        self.root = root
        c = Canvas(self.root, width=500, height=400, background='black')
        c.create_text(250, 90, text="Merry Christmas", font='Times 28 bold italic', fill='red')
        c.create_text(250, 130, text="and", font='Times 15 bold italic', fill='white')
        c.create_text(250, 170, text="Happy New Year", font='Times 28 bold italic', fill='green')
        c.pack()
        santa = Button(self.root, text="Click me!", command=self.santa_click)
        santa_window = c.create_window(200, 300, anchor=NW, window=santa)

    def santa_click(self):
        print "You clicked me!\n"

root = Tk()
root.title("D Day Test")
d_day = D_day(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Modify the `santa_click` method to change the behavior. I'll let you work on that one.

Comment: thanks for your comment! I'm working on changing the behavior right now but I have one question. Is there a way to make the santa button appear on canvas? I tried the c.create_window under class but it doesnt seem to work. thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated the template so that the `santa` button is drawn on the `c` canvas.

Comment: thanks the button's on canvas now! I tried to change the button to an image like I wrote on the original code but when I add those lines the button deactivates and comes out grey with no image, just bigger. Can you tell me what the problem is? Oh and I'm having trouble with the santa_click too.. is there a way to make it command so it callsbacka class?